# React: Why child stopped re-render the 3rd times

Tags: reactjs

I have a question why the child component didn't re-render at 3d time.

Please have a look of the code below, I have a `Parent` component which has a state hook, and pass the setState function do the `Child` component. In the Child, it has a timeout which will change the state to false after 2 sec. Also, I `console.log` when Parent or Child component renders.

See the console log underneath the code, I can understand why both components will re-render twice and when the Parent component re-render at 3rd time, but I don't understand why Child stop re-render 3rd time as well?

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lift-up-pass-down-state-0wk5l)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Parent() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  console.log("rendering Parent", loading);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? "Parent is loading" : "Loaded"}
      <Child onLoading={setLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ onLoading }) {
  console.log("rendering Child");
  setTimeout(() => onLoading(false), 2000);
  return <div>Order</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

```
rendering Parent true          
rendering Child 
rendering Parent false  // Parent state changed, parent render
rendering Child         // Child props haven't changed, why Child render?
rendering Parent false  // Parent state unchanged, parent only re-renders itself?
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your state loading variable has only two possible values (true and then false).  After you set it false it no longer changes and therefore does not need to re-render.  For illustration purposes, try changing your loading boolean into an integer.  Add one instead of flipping it to false and then see how it will keep re-rendering every 2 seconds forever and ever until you close the browser.  Something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Parent() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(0);
  console.log("rendering Parent", loading);

  function Child({ onLoading }) {
    console.log("rendering Child");
    setTimeout(() => onLoading(loading+1), 2000);
    return <div>Order {loading}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading === 0 ? "Parent is loading" : "Loaded " + loading + " times"}
      <Child onLoading={setLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```